# Printing only NON-BOUNDARY and CORNER elements of an (n*n) array

Tags: java

I am to write a program that prints ONLY the NON-BOUNDARY AND CORNER elements of an (n*n) array, for my assignment, and this is the main part of the code:
[image]

The output I am getting is this:
[image]

As you can see, the non-boundary elements (6,7,10,11) are not in their correct positions, which I believe, is because of incorrect printing of tab spaces within the loop. (My code is totally a mess)  I would like some help or suggestions to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: You always want a tab unless it's the 1st column, so the 1st line of code after starting your loops should be `if (j!=0) System.out.print("\t");`. Remove all other tabs (all your else blocks).

Answer (score 2):

I generally find that flattening things (the if-conditions in particular), and putting conditions into boolean-returning methods helps.  Try something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++ {
    if (isCorner(i,j,n) || !isEdge(i,j,n)) {
//...
    } else {
//...
    }
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

where `isCorner(i,j,n)` and `isEdge(i,j,n)` are defined something like

```
public boolean isCorner(int row, int column, int gridSize) {
//...
}
```

Comment: Just make sure that you print a tab in both the if and the else branch, following the number (if there is one).  You may want to consider using System.out.printf(...) along with spaces instead of tabs (as suggested by Joop Eggen) if the alignment isn't good enough (I don't use System.out.printf enough to remember the syntax).   @AjahnCharles I would assume that it's ok for the "squares" on the right edge of the grid to contain tabs after the numbers.

Comment: I assumed it wasn't, but if that is the case just move the print to the end with no condition (don't add it to all branches).

Answer (score 1):

A you got a solution, just missing spaces, I'll add some smart things:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        boolean visible = (i % (n - 1) == 0) == (j % (n - 1) == 0);
        if (visible) {
            System.out.printf(" %4d", a[i][j]);
        } else {
            System.out.print("     ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

No longer any problems with tabs `"\t"`, though I used spaces here.

Keep it simple, too many cases just cause problems - as you experienced.
The trick here is to consider whether to print or not. Hence I started with
a variable `visible`.

The border condition

```
i == 0 || i == n - 1
```

could also be written with modulo as

```
i % (n - 1) == 0
```

If this is "too smart", hard to grasp reading:

```
        boolean iOnBorder = i % (n - 1) == 0;
        boolean jOnBorder = j % (n - 1) == 0;
        boolean visible = iOnBorder == jOnBorder;
```

The "X" pattern checks the _equivalence of i-on-border and j-on-border.

For the rest: formatted printf allows padding of a number.

Comment: Thanks! I will keep that in mind in my future programs :)

Comment: Definitely prefer your edit (declaring names for the intermediates). I was arm-deep into XOR when you posted this! Mod and equality are both clever.

Comment: @AjahnCharles yeah I can see the XOR rising in mind. In fact my solution is _suspiciously too smart_. If this is homework, the official solution might well give this "very intelligent" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this i have optimized your if condition
No need to again check for `i == 0` or `i == n-1`

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){

            if(i==0 || i==n-1){
                if(j==0 || j==n-1){
                    System.out.print(a[i][j]);
                }
            }else{
                if(j != 0 && j!= n-1){
                    System.out.print(a[i][j]);
                }
            }
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: @UserKunal123 Great to hear that its working.  
Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Just gave a try in case you might find it helpful.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
   int[][] ar = new int[4][4];
   int[] input = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
   int pointer=0;
   int imin=0,jmin=0,imax=3,jmax=3;
   for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
       for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
           ar[i][j]=input[pointer];
           pointer++;
       }
   }
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            if(!((i==imax && j==jmin)||(i==imin && j==jmax)||i==j) && //For skipping the corners
                    (i == imin || j == jmin || i == imax || j == jmax)){// Not to print the borders
                    continue;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(ar[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```